# Import from TFS to VSTS stuck at “Restoring your collection”

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops

Our import is stuck at step 1 of 7 "Restoring your collection". Any suggestions?

As of 11/1/2017 it has been running for **70hrs**

Comment: How big is the BACPAC?

Comment: Are there any warning? Check the [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-troubleshooting) article.

Comment: @starain-MSFT There are no warnings.  I did check the Troubleshooting guide and there is nothing there.

Comment: @DanielMann The DACPAC is 17.8 GB

Comment: Is it still in process? Are there errors in Event Viewer?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Yes, it is still in progress, see my edit.  

"... errors in Event Viewer" I'm confused, this is not on my machine and i have no access to the machine that it is being imported on.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-overview for what we are doing.  We are on the last step of Importing.

Comment: What happened in the end?

Comment: @AndrewRimmer we contacted support and they did some things on their end.